# Elegant solution to the Magic Hexagon problem

Tags: strategy, magic-square

### The Magic Hexagon Problem

[image: Magic Hexagon]

> A magic hexagon of order $n$ is an arrangement of close-packed hexagons containing the numbers $1, 2, ..., H_{n-1}$, where $H_n$ is the $n^{th}$ hex number such that the numbers along each straight line add up to the same sum. (Here, the hex numbers are i.e., $1, 7, 19, 37, 61, 91, 127$, ...; [Sloane's A003215](https://oeis.org/A003215%7D). In the above magic hexagon of order $n=3$, each line (those of lengths $3$, $4$, and $5$) adds up to $38$.

From [Wolfram's Magic Hexagon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MagicHexagon.html).

Here is the programming puzzles entry to the [Magic Hexagon problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/code-solution-for-the-magic-hexagon). As you can see, the solutions there use appropriate systems of linear equations, and then try all the possibilities until it finds one. Boring, but effective; and can't be done by a human in a reasonable amount of time.

This is [de la Loubere's method](http://britton.disted.camosun.bc.ca/magicsq/magic.html) for magic squares. Much cleaner and more beautiful, and a human can do this process easily.

I want to know, is there such a solution / methodology to the Magic Hexagon problem that has the elegance of de la Loubere's method? How would you begin the process of coming up with one?

Comment: https://youtu.be/ZkVSRwFWjy0?si=eCP7Or7DgLNap8Tv shows a strategy which reduces brute-forcing to only 120 attempts, which can be done by a human relatively fast.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the article, the Magic Hexagon is the only one that exists (aside from n=1). There wouldn't be a simpler method for generating one, because no other hexagons of order 2 or >3 would have a solution. Quoting from the last paragraph:

> Trigg showed that the magic constant for an order n hexagon would be
>   (9(n^4-2n^3+2n^2-n)+2)/(2(2n-1)), the first few of which are
>   1, 28/3, 38, 703/7, 1891/9, 4186/11, ... (Sloane's A097361 and A097362),
>   which requires 5/(2n-1) to be an integer for a solution to exist.
>   But this is an integer for only n=1 (the trivial case of a single hexagon)
>   and Adams's n=3 (Gardner 1984, p. 24).

If I had to guess, I might claim the n=3 magic hexagon working at all is just a coincidence.

Comment: What does coincidence even mean in this context?